# How to detect if App Launch was user-initiated?

Tags: ios, swift

As we all know, `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` callback is called after app is almost ready to run, but there are cases, that push notifications, voip-push notifications, etc. do call this method as well, when app terminated to perform some tasks.

I need a solid answer, is there a way to tell when app launch was user-initiated, or something else did order app launch from background?

Is it safe to assume that the method parameter `launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?` will always be nil on user-initiated launch?

Comment: One question at a time please.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to assume that the method parameter `launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?` will always be nil on user-initiated launch?

No, absolutely not. For example if the user launches your app by way of a Quick Action, that is user-initiated but the Quick Action will be in the launch options.

However, if the `launchOptions` is empty, you can pretty much rely on the fact that the user tapped the app's icon in the springboard.

Comment: Ok but is there a way to tell if the app had launched just by user-initiated action, i.e. user tapped on app icon? Is there an expression statement for that case that I can use?

Comment: If your definition of user-initiated is that the user tapped on the app icon in the springboard, then yes, you can use the empty `launchOptions` to indicate that. But what I'm saying is that that is not the only user-initiated way of launching the app.